# Twitter API - which authentication flow to use for twitter status updates?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Twitter show 2 types of user-application authentication flows:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/3-legged-oauth  https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/log-in-with-twitter/guides/implementing-sign-in-with-twitter

I am building an app that requires the user to sign in once with their Twitter account, and then my app will send status updates on behalf of the user, entirely from the background, without user intervention.

I am asking this question because in the first link, it says that "The user will always be prompted to authorize access to your application, even if access was previously granted" So its not quite clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

The two types of authentication flow you're referring to in the documentation are actually *the same*. Sign-in with Twitter implements the 3 legged OAuth (user auth) flow. You must have user context / authentication in order to send Tweets.